# invalid users for shared

Tags: linux, shared-folders

I have a domain controller configured with ubuntu. For the shares I use smb.conf.
My question is, when I create a shared resource with the parameter: ***invalid users*** (so they don't have access) why does it ask me for a username and password to access the resource?
Is it possible that don't ask me? Thanks a lot.